# simple python program segmentation fault

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

A simple program to open and close 2 doors with servo motor depending on the content of `unlock.txt` file.

It just give `Segmentation Fault`.

I did:

```
ulimit -s 20000
```

Earlier it was around 8000, since i am on my raspberry pi 3.

Still getting `Segmentation Fault`.

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(38,GPIO.LOW)

pwm1=GPIO.PWM(40,50)
pwm2=GPIO.PWM(38,50)

flag=0
prevlok=0

while(True):

    with open('/home/pi/Documents/HAP/unlock.txt','r') as f1:
        unlock=f1.read()

    if flag == 0:
        if unlock == '1':
            pwm1.start(2.5)
            pwm2.start(2.5)
            sleep(2)
            pwm1.stop()
            pwm2.stop()
            flag=1
        else:
            pwm1.start(7.5)
            pwm2.start(7.5)
            sleep(2)
            pwm1.stop()
            pwm2.stop()
            flag=1

    if prevlok != unlock:
        flag=0
    else:
        flag=1

    prevlok=unlock
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for reading...
I fixed the issue with following code...
Wondering if there is a way to stop pwm or not run servo motor to save power in the loop, I was trying to do in the question...

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(38,GPIO.LOW)

pwm1=GPIO.PWM(40,50)
pwm2=GPIO.PWM(38,50)
pwm1.start(7.5)
pwm2.start(7.5)

flag=1
prevlok=0

while(True):

    with open('/home/pi/Documents/HAP/unlock.txt','r') as f1:
        unlock=f1.read()

    if flag == 1:
        if unlock == '1':
            pwm1.ChangeDutyCycle(2.5)
            pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(2.5)
            sleep(2)
            flag=0
        else:
            pwm1.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
            pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5)
            sleep(2)
            flag=0

    if prevlok != unlock:
        flag=1
    else:
        flag=0

    prevlok=unlock
```